# Parsing API response with GO

Tags: go, finnhub

I'm using the `finnhub` REST API but I'm having an issue parsing and displaying the response sent back from the API.

Here is my code:

```
func newTicker(s []string) {
    cfg := finnhub.NewConfiguration()
    cfg.AddDefaultHeader("X-Finnhub-Token", "api_key")
    finnhubClient := finnhub.NewAPIClient(cfg).DefaultApi

    res, _, _ := finnhubClient.SymbolSearch(context.Background()).Q("AAPL").Execute()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", reflect.TypeOf(res))
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Response:  {0xc0003ac168 0xc0003901f8}
TYPE:  finnhub.SymbolLookup
```

How do I go about actually viewing the data from the response and why is the response `{0xc0003ac168 0xc0003901f8}`?

#### WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:

Just iterate through the response and view the the data.

Comment: You're printing a structure that contains two pointers. Perhaps read the [API documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Finnhub-Stock-API/finnhub-go/v2#SymbolLookup) to know what it contains.

Comment: Ah, so that values are "pointers". That is good to know

Answer (score 2):

This response `{0xc0003ac168 0xc0003901f8}` is the default textual representation of pointer values. The printed hexes are the memory addresses.

By the way the format verb `%+v` prints the field names, so you're probably showing the output of `%v` instead.

Unless the struct implements the `Stringer` interface, you can't show what the pointers are referencing with just fmt verbs. The other option is `%#v` which adds type information, but that's about it.

You could define your own type as:

```
type StringerSymbolLookup finnhub.SymbolLookup
```

...and add a `String() string` method on it to implement `Stringer` and print the values in a human readable format. Something akin to what I exemplified [in this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KjQp8Woz-9s). Since [`finnhub.SymbolLookup`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Finnhub-Stock-API/finnhub-go/v2#SymbolLookup) has one field which is maybe unwieldy to stringify, but has json tags on both fields, you can just marshal to JSON and print that instead.

Though, if your goal is to just inspect the response for development purposes, stepping through it with a debugger may be your best bet.